# Looking for feedback/insight on a rails application I'm building using Twilio API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, sms

​​Hi all, I am not a very experienced developer but am working on delivering an application for a client that revolves around sending sms notifications to pharmacies. I am mainly looking for some insight and feedback on scalability implications and what could be some ways to address them or what to look out for.  Would like to plan ahead and get some feedback before I start coding this up.

I plan to build the frontend with React and the backend with Ruby on Rails with a Postgres DB. Looking to deploy the app on Heroku.

The app will facilitate communication between patients and pharmacies.  Goal is to have a public app that any patient has access to and submits a request for some medication. Then, every pharmacy that is enrolled in the app (admin will enroll them) will receive an sms that patient x needs y medication with z quantity.  The pharmacy will then either respond back to the request if they have the medication in stock or decide not to respond if medication is not in stock.

I will be using two main models:

1. Pharmacy model with phone number as a string attribute
2. request model with medication name, medication strength, and phoneNumber of patient making request. All string attributes.

I will be using the Twilio API to handle outbound and inbound sms.  Here is my plan:

1. When patient submits a request on the app (with their phone number included), make a request to my backend api endpoint and I will use Twilio API to send an sms to every pharmacy in my db.  At max enrollment, I could have 1000 pharmacies.  Luckily, Twilio has some nice built in features for sending sms at this scale while circumventing api rate limits and carrier filtering.
2. If a pharmacy has the med in stock, they will be prompted to respond with the request number (plan to use the primary key here) that will be included with each sms.  Twilio uses a webhook url that I can configure to send to my backend.  My plan here was to make a query to find the request based on the request number (or primary id) sent back by the pharmacy.  Once I find the request, I can then send an sms to the phone number(patient) associated with the request.

I guess what I am not too experienced in is scalability and am not sure what to expect specifically on the second part of the process.  In the worst case, all 1000 pharmacies have the medication in stock (probably would never happen) and I will be getting 1000 messages sent to my backend within a short time frame, all while making a query for each message to my db to find the associated request and phone number of the patient.

Thoughts? Areas of improvement? Things to look out for?

I would appreciate any and all feedback!  Thank you.

Comment: how are the pharmacies receiving the SMS requests for meds? On their phones?

Comment: I know lots of devs use React or similar js framework in conjunction with Rails. I have done that a couple of times and I can say that it adds an unbelievable amount of dev and maintenance effort. I'm following with enthusiasm the capabilities of the Rails 7 hotwire feature. I think you can do what you need with mimimal js (stimulusjs), no SMS, just Rails. Much more maintainable. Keep it simple.

Comment: @LesNightingill Yes idea is to have pharmacists of a particular pharmacy to receive the messages on their phone.